# How to sum and get average of dynamic rows

Tags: mysql

I am new in MySql and help will be much appreciated

I had this assignment which is **to get the sum and average of dynamic rows in the table**. The table looks like

```
tbl_grade
id    scores
1     10
1     11
1     9
1     10
1     6
2     10
2     9
2     10
```

I want to show the results like this

```
id    sum    average
1     46     9.2
2     29     9.7
```

Hope anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: Simple `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple query using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause and the aggregate methods **SUM** and **AVG**. For a better understanding about grouping and aggregate methods, please read next: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(scores),
    AVG(scores)
FROM
    tbl_grade
GROUP BY
    id
```